# Alignment issue in high charts

Tags: highcharts

I am working on high charts (pie and bar). while page loads, charts are not center aligned, but as soon as I do inspect element it gets aligned. Can anyone suggest possible reasons?

Comment: can you share your code sample here..

Answer (score 0):

In the pie chart you have `center` parameter which allows you to position chart.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/40h671s3/